# Change menu shortcuts in Evolution

Tags: debian, configuration, keyboard-shortcuts, evolution

I'm trying to change menu shortcuts in the E-mail client Evolution, specifically removing the "send message" via "Ctrl-Enter" shortcut, but can't figure out how.

My system is rather new:

- Debian 8 Jessie 64bit
- Gnome 3.14.1
- Evolution 3.12.9

I searched the net for hours and tried the following solutions. Unfortunately, none of them worked:

1. use gconf-editor to set desktop->gnome->interface->can_change_accels to true. Then restart Evolution, compose a new message, mouse-hover over the menu item and press a new key-combination
2. Same as solution 1, but use dconf-editor to set org->gnome->desktop->interface->can-change-accels to true
3. Same as solution 1, but use gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface can-change-accels true
4. Edit ~/.config/evolution/accels. Uncomment "Actions/mailto/send-message" and assign a new key-binding.
5. Looked for other config files in various locations, but they didn't exist on my system: ~/.evolution/, ~/.gnome2/accels/evolution
6. Evolution itself doesn't seem to have any menu/option for changing the shortcuts

I hope someone can help me out with this one.

Comment: I've got the same problem! Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I solved editing ~/.config/evolution/accels , removing the initial ";" and specifying the new shortcut.
Evolution must be closed, since it apparently rewrite the file on closure.

I found the solution in comments here: https://major.io/2015/11/27/custom-keyboard-shortcuts-for-evolution-in-gnome/

Comment: There's no `~/.config/evolution/accels` file. At least not with a 3.44.2 Evolution version. I also tried to search for the `gtk_accel_path` keyword in the entire `~/.config/evolution/` directory and there were no matches ‍♂️